# Adapter siempre me muestra el mismo item en ListView

Tags: android, google-hoja-de-cálculo, android-listview, baseadapter, google-sheets

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación Android que utiliza Google Sheets como base de datos. El funcionamiento, básicamente,es que escaneo un código de barras de un libro, me guarda toda la información sobre este libro en la hoja de Google Sheets, y lo que quiero es que estar información me la muestre en un  `ListView`.

Cuando escaneo dos libros, me los guarda correctamente en la hoja, pero cuando quiero mostrar esta información en el  `ListView`, me muestra el último que he insertado, y no entiendo por qué.

A continuación voy mostrando el código y explicando lo que me devuelve:

El siguiente método lee la información de la hoja de cálculo y lo inserta en el `List<Strings>results`:

```
private List<String> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {

        String range = "Sheet1!A2:I";
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        ValueRange response = CreateSpreadsheets.mService.spreadsheets().values()
                //.get(CreateSpreadsheets.spreadsheet_id, range)
                .get(sheet_id, range)
                .execute();
        List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
        System.out.println(values);
        if (values != null) {
            for (List row : values) {
                results.add(row.get(0) + "," + row.get(6));
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
```

A continuación, el `postExecute`

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> results) {
        mProgress.hide();
        if (results == null || results.size() == 0) {
           // emptyText.setText(R.string.empty);
        } else {
            if(read_only.equals("no")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Spreadsheets.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                //  mOutputText.setText("Se ha aÃ±adido un libro a su lista");
            }
            else {
                resultados = new ArrayList<BookItem>();
                System.out.println(results);
                int length = results.size();
                System.out.println(length);
                int i;
                for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    String string = results.get(i);
                    System.out.println("string results get (i)" + string);
                    String[] partes = string.split(",");
                    String titulo = partes[0];
                    String portada = partes[1];
                    System.out.println(titulo + "," + portada);
                    book = new BookItem(titulo, portada);
                    resultados.add(book);
                }
                read_only = "no";
                rellenar();
            }
        }
    }
```

Aquí he puesto un par de prints para comprobar que realmente me está devolviendo todos los libros que tengo guardados, y efectivamente, así es:

```
I/System.out: string results get (i)Todo esto te daré,No portada
I/System.out: Todo esto te daré,No portada
I/System.out: string results get (i)La elegancia del erizo,http://books.google.com/books/content?id=od5GRQAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api
I/System.out: La elegancia del erizo,http://books.google.com/books/content?id=od5GRQAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api
```

Después, la función `rellenar()`, hace lo siguiente:

```
public void rellenar(){
        adapter = new BookAdapter(context, resultados, sheet_id);
        bookList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

A continuación os dejo el código de mi `BookAdapter`:

```
public class BookAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

List<BookItem> items;
private Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;


public BookAdapter(Context context, List<BookItem> items) {
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public BookItem getItem(int position) {
    return this.items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fila_lista_miestanteria, viewGroup, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title_item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.book_title_item);
        holder.favorite = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.favorite);
        holder.cover_item = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.book_cover_item);

        holder.title_item.setText(this.items.get(position).getTitle());
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    BookItem bookItem = getItem(position);
    System.out.println("position en bookdapter " + getItem(position));
    holder.title_item.setText(bookItem.getTitle());
    System.out.println("Titulo: " + bookItem.getTitle());
    holder.favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp);
    final String url = bookItem.getCover();
    Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(holder.cover_item);

    return convertView; }
```

Los prints que he puesto (con el for, ahora comentado) parece que me están devolviendo dos libros diferentes:

```
I/System.out: size 2
I/System.out: position com.example.apptfg.BookItem@aba768a
I/System.out: 2
I/System.out: position com.example.apptfg.BookItem@aba768a
I/System.out: size 2
I/System.out: position com.example.apptfg.BookItem@d17156
I/System.out: 2
I/System.out: position com.example.apptfg.BookItem@d17156
```

Pero finalmente el resultado en mi `ListView` es el último libro que he insertado, y no los dos que tengo en la lista:

[image: ListView]

¿Alguien me podría ayudar? Muchísimas gracias por adelantado!

Comment: Dos recomendaciones, la primera es que hagas una depuración paso a paso, es muy probable que así encuentres el error, la segunda es que pongas estas tres lineas a nivel del método para evitar repetir código innecesariamente, cover_item = (ImageView) view.getTag(R.id.book_cover_item);
        title_item = (TextView)view.getTag(R.id.book_title_item);
        favorite = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.favorite);

Answer (score 1):

te recomiendo que organices un poco mejor tu codigo. Repites demasiadas partes lo cual te puede llevar a errores. Lo segundo tienes un error en esta parte

```
else {
        cover_item = (ImageView) view.getTag(R.id.book_cover_item);
        title_item = (TextView)view.getTag(R.id.book_title_item);
        favorite = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.favorite);
        favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp);
        favorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                BookItem bookItem = getItem(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,AnhadirFavorito.class);
                intent.putExtra("book_fav","si");
                intent.putExtra("title", bookItem.getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("sheet_id",sheet_id);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

getTag y setTag, es una forma de agregar información a un view, no para encontrarlo. Recuerda que el view solo es nulo en la primera interaccion. posteiormente ya no lo es y cuando quieres asignar nuevamente cover_item al elemento en vista no lo va a encontrar. Debes cambiarlo por

```
else {
        cover_item = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.book_cover_item);
        title_item = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.book_title_item);
        favorite = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.favorite);
        favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp);
        favorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                BookItem bookItem = getItem(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,AnhadirFavorito.class);
                intent.putExtra("book_fav","si");
                intent.putExtra("title", bookItem.getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("sheet_id",sheet_id);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

Con eso deberia funcinar.

Comment: Sigue sin funcionarme...entonces cuando hago if(view==null) no uso getTag y setTag? Muchisimas gracias!

Comment: Son cosas independientes amigo. setTag y getTag sirven para guardar informacion en un view, como un objeto en caso que lo quieras. Si eso no te soluciona el problema te recomienda que hagas un debug y mires que objeto se muestra en pantalla en cada interaccion

Comment: He modificado el código y sigue sin funcionar. He visto muchos ejemplos por internet y todos funcionan, por lo que no puedo entender por qué el mío no. Aunque en la clase Spreadsheets le pasa todos los libros que hay en la hoja (esto lo sé seguro, lo he comprobado), el Adapter siempre me devuelve el mismo libro, el último que he insertado. He modificado la entrada para añadir el nuevo código de BookAdapter. Alguien me podría ayudar?

Comment: Sube el codigo a un reposotorio en github si deseas, me lo compartes y me explicas como se hace funcionar (con la hoja de calculo que usa como fuente de datos y esas cosas) y lo intento arreglar. Viendo el codigo asi no mas no puedo dar una resputa.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu interés y ayuda, pero ya he dado con la solución. El problema estaba BookItem,  tenía dos variables static; cambiándolas a private comenzó a funcionar. Gracias de nuevo!